# How can I anchor my DynamicLayout to the bottom of my canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am working on a custom `View` that includes frequently updated text that I want to anchor to the bottom of the canvas.

The text length changes as well, and I'd like it to wrap, moving up the screen as more lines are needed.  (`DynamicLayout` thus seems like a solid choice for automating this)

However, I don't see any options in the docs about specifying where on my canvas the text is drawn or in which direction it should "grow".

Here is my initialization:

```
TextPaint subtleTextPaint = new TextPaint();
DynamicLayout dl = new DynamicLayout(text,subtleTextPaint,getWidth()
    ,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,1,0,true);
```

And in `onDraw()`, I simply pass the canvas to the `DynamicLayout` object like so:

```
dl.draw(c);
```

Right now, the text is drawn at the very top of the screen and word-wraps downwards as the text gets longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of searching, I found nothing that did what I wanted.  So, in true hacker style, I created my own solution.  By extending the `DynamicLayout` class and overwriting the `getLineTop()` function, I was able to achieve the functionality I was looking for.

I've posted the [source code here](http://kevinhulin.com/wordpress/?p=9).

Answer (score 0):

What i think 1st you get the Width of the screen and then set the Text with the X y according to your screen dimension 
that will work 
snippet is following

```
 width=canvas.getWidth();

        if(width==720)
        {
            canvas.drawText(String, x , y, drawText);
        }
        else if(width==480)
        {
            canvas.drawText(String, x , (y, drawText);
        }
        else 
        {
            canvas.drawText(String, x , (y, drawText);
        }
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid calculating widths and linebreaks manually.  The  `android.text.DynamicLayout` class appears to do these calculations for me.